# WebView send referrer to server

Tags: android, android-webview

How to send a referer  in a url for a webView? There exists an method loadUrl (String url, Map additionalHttpHeaders), but i have a 7 Api.

That's how I was trying

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("");
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 String query = "referer=http://donmob.com/";
 mWebView.postUrl("http://donmob.com/",EncodingUtils.getBytes(query, "BASE64"));
```

Comment: tell us what you have tried so far

Comment: tried by WebView.PostUrl(), but did not work, that maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

i think the below posts have your answer

[How to send a URL request as 'Referer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903496/how-to-send-a-url-request-as-referer)

[How to send a referer request in a url for a webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342399/how-to-send-a-referer-request-in-a-url-for-a-webview)

Here they uses loadUrl() with additionalHttpHeaders parameter and this feature is available  from Android 2.2 onwards.

Comment: then please explain your problem in more detail with code samples that you have tried. i hope, this will help you to get more specific answers