# HTTP Referer Header in Android

Tags: android, http-referer

Can anyone please tell me that how we use Referer Header in android. As i am working on tool to check for vulnerable code and as using Referer header in an application is not safe so can please anyone tell me syntax for that in android..specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903496/how-to-send-a-url-request-as-referer?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

With `HttpGet`, `HttpPost` you can edit the request headers:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://your.url.com");
request.addHeader("Referer", "http://referer.url.com");
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
```

Comment: thanks Jong for your reply.. but actually i want that vulnerable code for referer header